# How can i continue the loop after getting value from function?

Tags: loops, lua, pause

as i write in title, I have small question it's about loop!
i've small loop, ok?
i want pause loop in each value and call a function and wait a response from function, if function give any value i want to continue the loop!
anyone have idea or suggest to help me at this?
please don't give codes includes/or needs LUA Librares

Comment: _i've small loop, ok?_ Okay... where is it?

Comment: i want an example, doing same idea

Comment: I didn't understand you, anyway i'll give you a small code but not working! code:   `function DoSomething( value ) while ( value < 50 ) do value = value + 1 end if ( value >= 50 ) then return true end end Table = { 1, 3 , 5 } for _, v in pairs ( Table ) do bool = DoSomething( v ) if ( bool == true ) then print ( 'done' ) end end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function calls inside loops will block by default in Lua (and any other language I can think of). So you do not have to worry about that. The loop won't continue as long the function doesn't return a value.

```
function is_done(x)
  if x == 5 then
    return true
  end
  return false
end

for i=1,10 do
  if is_done(i) then
    print('done!')
    break
  end
end
```

In the above example the loop breaks (stops) when `i` is equal to 5.